# How to create a bucket with Public Read Access?

Tags: amazon-s3, serverless

I´d like to enable Public Read-Access on all items in my Bucket that are in the "public" folder in the serverless.yml file.

Currently this is definition code i use to declare my bucket. Its a bit of copy and paste from one of the serverless-stack examples.

```
Resources:
  AttachmentsBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      AccessControl: PublicRead
      # Set the CORS policy
      BucketName: range-picker-bucket-${self:custom.stage}
      CorsConfiguration:
        CorsRules:
          -
            AllowedOrigins:
              - '*'
            AllowedHeaders:
              - '*'
            AllowedMethods:
              - GET
              - PUT
              - POST
              - DELETE
              - HEAD
            MaxAge: 3000

# Print out the name of the bucket that is created
Outputs:
  AttachmentsBucketName:
    Value:
      Ref: AttachmentsBucket
```

Now when i try to use a url for a file, it returns access denied. I manually have to set the public read permission for every file by hand in the aws-s3 web interface.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of using `CorsConfiguration` on the bucket, you need to [attach a bucket policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-policy-language-overview.html) to it. Try the following:

```
Resources:
  AttachmentsBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: range-picker-bucket-${self:custom.stage}

  AttachmentsBucketAllowPublicReadPolicy:
    Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref AttachmentsBucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement: 
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: 
              - "s3:GetObject"
            Resource: 
              - !Join ['/', [!Ref AttachmentsBucket, 'public']]
            Principal: "*"
```

Comment: Also, the bucket needs to be configured to for **S3 Block Public Access**. See the CloudFormation part of: [Amazon S3 Block Public Access – Another Layer of Protection for Your Accounts and Buckets | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-block-public-access-another-layer-of-protection-for-your-accounts-and-buckets/)

Comment: I wasn't able to get this example to work.  After searching around for documentation to describe what the Resource in the policy was supposed to be, I gave up and hard coded it to "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::{NAME_OF_YOUR_BUCKET_HERE}/*".  That at least, is working

Answer (score 6):

Accepted answer didn't work for me. CloudFormation failed to update the resource with the error:

`Action does not apply to any resource(s) in statement (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicy; Request ID: <...>; S3 Extended Request ID: <...>; Proxy: null)`

It appears the wildcard was missing in the resource definition. Full snippet that worked for me:

```yaml
PublicBucket:
  Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
  Properties:
    BucketName: 'public-bucket-name'

PublicBucketPolicy:
  Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
  Properties:
    Bucket: !Ref PublicBucket
    PolicyDocument:
      Version: '2012-10-17'
      Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - 's3:GetObject'
          Resource:
            - !Join ['/', [!GetAtt [PublicBucket, Arn], '*']]
          Principal: '*'
```

Answer (score 1):

As the others have said, you need to implement a **Bucket Policy** such as this one:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadForGetBucketObjects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::{NAME_OF_YOUR_BUCKET_HERE}/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This can be done in the AWS console by selecting the **Bucket**, then **Permissions**, then **Bucket Policy**.  Looks like @Milan C. is indicating how to declare this in a **serverless.yml** file.

Answer (score 0):

This approach worked for me:

```
 Resources:
    StaticAssetsBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: ${sls:stage}.${self:service}.static-assets
        AccessControl: PublicRead
    PublicBucketPolicy:
      Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
      Properties:
        Bucket: !Ref StaticAssetsBucket
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - "s3:GetObject"
              Resource:
                - !Sub "${StaticAssetsBucket.Arn}/*"
              Principal: "*"
```