# give public read and view access to s3 bucket objects using cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I am writing a AWS cloudformation template to receive a file inside a s3 bucket from Kinesis Firehose. I have gave public read access to the bucket (bucket is public) but when i access the file inside the bucket using object URL, i get "The XML file does not appear to have any style associated with it" error and it says access denied. However the object (JSON file) is downloadable.

I have given full access to the s3 bucket

```
Resources:

# Create s3 bucket
MyS3Bucket:
 Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
 Properties:
    BucketName: health-app-buckett
    AccessControl: PublicRead

# Create Role
S3BucketRole:
 Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
 Properties:
  AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
    Statement:
      - Effect: Allow
        Principal:
          Service:
            - s3.amazonaws.com
        Action:
          - 'sts:AssumeRole'

#Create policy for bucket
S3BucketPolicies:
 Type: 'AWS::IAM::Policy'
 Properties:
  PolicyName: S3BucketPolicy
  PolicyDocument:
    Statement:
      - Sid: PublicReadForGetBucketObjects
        Effect: Allow
        Action: 's3:GetObject'
        Resource: !Join
          - ''
          - - 'arn:aws:s3:::'
            - !Ref MyS3Bucket
            - /*
  Roles:
    - !Ref S3BucketRole
```

I want to be able to view the file using Object URL

Comment: Similar question answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54259512/how-to-create-a-bucket-with-public-read-access

Comment: The answer above solves it

Answer (score 2):

You need to add PublicAccessBlockConfiguration to your template

```yaml
MyS3Bucket:
  Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
  Properties:
    BucketName: health-app-bucket
    AccessControl: PublicRead
    PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
      BlockPublicAcls: false
      BlockPublicPolicy: false
      IgnorePublicAcls: false
      RestrictPublicBuckets: false
```

When pushing your objects to S3, you'll still need to put them with `ACL: public-read`.

**Note:** the `AccessControl: PublicRead` will grant **list** permission on your bucket allowing all objects to be found publically.

Comment: If I try to deploy that, I get "Bucket cannot have public ACLs set with BlockPublicAccess enabled".

Comment: I am getting Bucket cannot have ACLs set with ObjectOwnership's BucketOwnerEnforced setting