# how to convert bucket policy json to serverless.yaml

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, yaml, serverless

I have been using serverless for sometime. I have been uploading images to s3 bucket. I created the s3 bucket in the aws console manually. Now, I am struggling to create s3 bucket via yaml and upload files in it due to per.

**I have successfully created s3 bucket via yaml using this yaml commands:**

```
 resources:      
  Resources:
   ProfPicBucketv4:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
       BucketName: 'prof-pic-bucketv4'
       # Set the CORS policy
       CorsConfiguration:
         CorsRules:
           -
             AllowedOrigins:
               - '*'
             AllowedHeaders:
               - '*'
             AllowedMethods:
               - GET
               - PUT
               - POST
               - DELETE
               - HEAD
```

**This is an equivalent to CORS configuration:**
[image: **enter image description here**]

**Now when I try to upload file it gives me access denied even with CORS configuration. My next goal would converting this image into yaml:**
[image]

I already have this:

```
service: campproject

provider:
  name: aws
  region: us-east-1

  # Lambda runs faster if we allocate the maximum memory to each function execution...
  memorySize: 3008
  timeout: 30

  runtime: nodejs10.x

  # Prevent storing revisions in AWS - We're storing them as Docker Images instead...
  versionFunctions: false

  stage: ${opt:stage, self:custom.defaultStage}
  profile: ${self:custom.awsProfiles.${self:provider.stage}}

  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "s3:ListBucket"
        - "s3:GetObject"
        - "s3:PutObject"
      Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::prof-pic-bucketv4/*"
```

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered here.

[Stackoverflow link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54259512/how-to-create-a-bucket-with-public-read-access)

```
Resources:
  AttachmentsBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: range-picker-bucket-${self:custom.stage}

  AttachmentsBucketAllowPublicReadPolicy:
    Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref AttachmentsBucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement: 
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: 
              - "s3:GetObject"
            Resource: 
              - !Join ['/', [!Ref AttachmentsBucket, 'public']]
            Principal: "*"
```